# Display of DIVA-GIS Gazetteer *.dbf Files in QGIS

Tags: qgis, dbf, diva-gis, gazetteer

I've looked through other questions/answers and not seen what I am looking for...

1. How do I display the contents of a DIVA-GIS Gazetteer *.dbf file in QGIS?

Ideally I would like to take contents of the dbf and display a symbol according to coordinate(s), defining symbol character from another column and finally labelling according to a fourth column.

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to open the DBF file in a Spreadsheet software (e.g., LibreOffice Calc or Excel), export it to CSV, and open it in QGIS using the `Add Delimited Text Layer` tool (find it in `Layer-->Add Layer-->`).

Being there, you can select fields for longitude (`X field`) and latitude (`Y field`).

[image]

Once points are loaded into QGIS, right click on that layer and go to `Properties-->Style`. Choose `Categorized` in the very first combo box. Select the field you want the symbology to be based on and click on `Classify` and `OK`.

[image]

Finally, for labeling points, go to `Properties-->Labels`, activate the `Label this layer with` check box, select the field you want labels from, and click `OK`.

[image]

You should see a result like this (I'm using DIVA-GIS Gazetteer data for Colombia):

[image]

Of course, you can set your own symbology and labeling properties, such as color, shape, font, and the like.